# How did Loki activate the Space Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

As Hawkeye put it, doors opens both ways.

Is there any indication how Loki is able to trigger the Tesseract and get to the Earth in the first place?

Comment: In the post credits scene of *Captain America* Loki was shown to already be on earth. though i don't know if this was before or after he met Thanos

Comment: Have you ever seen Loki could trigger the Tesseract or activate the Space stone by only himself?

Comment: I don't remember that Loki can activate the Space stone and don't think he can without any tools such as the staff to use mind stone in movie Avenger or in the end of the movie, he had to use a machine to activate space stone to open the space gate for aliens came.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Loki used Selvig for this.

In the end-credit scene of *Thor*, we can see that Loki was already influencing Selvig's mind.

> **Selvig:** What is it?
>
> **Fury:** Power, doctor. If we can figure out how to tap it, maybe unlimited power.
>
> **Loki:** Well, I guess that's worth a look.
>
> **Selvig:** Well, I guess that's worth a look.

We can't know how, but Loki made him to design the device and make it work so that it can open a door to let Loki teleport. It was planned near the end of *Thor* already.

Comment: I have a question, If Selvig was already under the Loki's spell, why did LOki had to do the *thing* again on Selvig, in Avengers?

Comment: He was influencing Selvig's mind. And when Loki uses the scepter, he brainwashes Selvig.

Comment: yeah, but why do the same thing again?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if he really opened it for Loki or if Loki just needed them to do stuff with the Tesseract. In a way of "opening the earth port" and with enough knowledge you can teleport there. Because Hawkeye explicit said that it was not manipulated from the earth side i.e. he didn't see anything suspicious done by Selvig

Comment: this answer makes sense, I had forgotten the post-credit scenes with Selvig being manipulated.